# Excel formula or VBA that

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with over 400,000 rows. A is the customer number, B customer name,  There may be two or more variations of the Name with the same number. I want to make the names the same relative to the number so in a pivot table there is only one row per customer number. Example of data below.

Column: A,

Customer Number

DEEU9999684

DEEU9999684

DEEU9999684

Column B "Customer Name:"

ZWICKAU-XX

ZWICKAU

ZWICKAU

To make it easier I sorted by customer number, and can use the first instance of the "Customer Name" when then "Customer number" changes and where the number are equal. So the above example all the names can be "ZWICKAU-XX"

I was trying a combination of IF(AND but that obviously doesn't work, example ... =IF(AND(A1=A2, B1=B2, B1, B2)

Hope someone can save me form having to manually scrub 400,000 records.

Thanks, dkmanley

Answer (score 0):

Enter the formula in cell C1: `=FALSE` (I mean enter text "FALSE" in C1)
and then copy this to column C: `=IF(A2=A1;TRUE;FALSE)` (Starting from C2)

Enter the formula in cell D1: `=A1`
Then copy this to column D: `=IF(C2=FALSE;B2;D1)` (Starting from D2)

Here is a sample:

```
1   a   FALSE   a
1   a   TRUE    a
1   a   TRUE    a
1   x   TRUE    a
1   x   TRUE    a
2   b   FALSE   b
2   b   TRUE    b
2   b   TRUE    b
2   bf  TRUE    b
2   c   TRUE    b
2   c   TRUE    b
3   d   FALSE   d
3   d   TRUE    d
3   d   TRUE    d
3   s   TRUE    d
3   c   TRUE    d
3   d   TRUE    d
3   s   TRUE    d
4   a   FALSE   a
4   d   TRUE    a
4   f   TRUE    a
4   g   TRUE    a
4   s   TRUE    a
4   a   TRUE    a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A1,A:A,0))
```

and copy down. The data does not need to be sorted. The formula will return the name for the first occurrence of the number, starting from the top.

[image]